# Multiple require_once and active folders

Tags: php, require-once

I'm trying to implement Google APIs in PHP on WAMP, but I can't even manage to include the files.

My code is the following :

```
<?php
  require_once "./vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php";
```

Client.php

```
require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';
require_once 'Google/Cache/File.php';
require_once 'Google/Cache/Memcache.php';
....
```

My error :

> Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to
>   open  stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on
>   line 18

How should I use include path, and similar commands to get Client.php to find what it wants ?

Comment: What is your directory structure, where is AssertionCredentials.php? At a guess, if you're trying to include it from Client.php, and Client.php is in the Google directory, then instead of 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php' it might be just 'Auth/AssertionCredentials.php'

Comment: I would gladly show you the structure of the directories,  but I am not yet allowed to post images. I don't think the problem lies in the Client.php file since it's the official one (I installed through composer).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways so that the file can be found. These include the absolute path or also using setting the include path. The include path can be set via:

- php.ini
- .htaccess
- ini_set function
- set_include_path function

Please goole the one most appropriate for your use

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using Composer.